Limitations on ReplayKit file sharing?
Problem
I'm using ReplayKit to save a screen recording, and once it is done it outputs to an URL.
When I print the URL I do get a local value, something like:
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E1A1A2CD-53A7-4FE0-894A-3F52377EAE72/tmp/D886623A-A42A-4D8D-ADD4-2D8705BC032F-recording.mov

At that point I want to ask the user to save or share the data that is located at this URL. To do that I'm using a UIActivityViewController and it works perfectly for short recordings (a few seconds).
My problem is that it just doesn't work for longer recording (ie larger files). It seems to start breaking around 30 seconds. There is no output at all, no warnings, no crash.

Is this a limit of ReplayKit? I'm still seeing an URL being generated, even for larger files, so it doesn't seem like it's the case.
Is this a limit of UIActivityViewController?

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

More details about the code
I'm using SwiftUI, so I use this:
struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var activityItems: [Any]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {}

}

Then the view looks like this (I simplified the code for the sake of discussion):
struct RecordButton: View {
    @State var showShareSheet = false
    @State var url: URL?
    @State var recording: Bool = false
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if(recording) {
                Task {
                    do {
                        self.url = try await stopRecording()
                        showShareSheet = true
                    } catch {
                        print("Error")
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                startRecording()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Record")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet, content: {
            ActivityViewController(activityItems: [url!])
        })
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        recorder.startRecording( handler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
        })
    }
    
    func stopRecording() async throws -> URL {
        let name = UUID().uuidString + "-recording.mov"
        let url = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
        try await recorder.stopRecording(withOutput: url)
        return url
    }


This really seems broken, I would have tried to startCapture and create a video file myself.
